# "My many" vs "many of my"

Tags: adjectives, pronouns

**My** many smiles begin with you.

Many of **my** smiles begin with you.

Are both sentences grammatically correct as well as idiomatic?Do they convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 3):

### They are grammatically correct, but they do not mean the same thing.

The first sentence you provided, 'my many smiles…' states that

1. The speaker has many smiles
2. The speaker's smiles all begin with the subject.

The second sentence, though, connotes that not all of the speaker's (not necessarily numerous) smiles begin with the subject, but many of them do.

Comment: I think you reversed the order of OP's examples.